# Instanciar método no Formulário instanciado

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá, estou com a seguinte dúvida, eu instanciei um novo formulário com o seguinte código:

```
Form frmDialog = new Form();
```

Bom, eu quero fazer o seguinte, no formulário em que eu instanciei esse novo Form, eu posso usar o seguinte código:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            switch(keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Escape:
                    Close();
                    break;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

Eu queria saber como faço pra instanciar esse método pra funcionar no frmDialog (Novo formulário.)

O que esse código faz: Quando eu pressiono a tecla Escape (ESC), o formulário fecha.

Comment: Precisa ser com esse seu método `ProcessCmdKey`? Não pode ser utilizando o `KeyDown` no frmDialog?

Comment: Não funcionou, mas obrigado mesmo assim, eu tava tentando fazer com os eventos KeyUp e KeyPress, agora sei desse evento.. :)

Comment: Opa, agora sim! Obrigado, agora sei por que não dava pra usar esses eventos no form.... Obrigado mesmo! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucas, quando você instancia um objeto do tipo `Form`, ele só terá os métodos e propriedades genéricos que já estão presentes no tipo `Form`. No caso, esse método está presente na classe do .NET:

> Form.ProcessCmdKey Method (Message, Keys)
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey.aspx

Mas, ele não terá essa funcionalidade específica que você quer.

Para fazer o que você quer, você teria que criar uma nova classe que herda a classe genérica `Form`, adicionando essa nova funcionalidade que você deseja. Então você poderia fazer assim:

```
class MeuForm : Form
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        switch(keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Escape:
                this.Close();
                break;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

E aí, na hora de usar essa versão modificada da classe `Form`, você teria que instanciar a **sua** classe:

```
MeuForm frmDialog = new MeuForm();
```

Embora você precise criar um objeto do tipo `MeuForm`, você poderia definir a variável como sendo do tipo `Form`, se precisasse, já que `MeuForm` herda a classe `Form`:

```
Form frmDialog = new MeuForm();
```

Entretanto, se você usar dessa segunda forma, o *intellisense* do Visual Studio não te mostrará propriedades e métodos públicos que sejam exclusivos da classe `MeuForm`, só mostrará os membros especificamente expostos pelo tipo `Form`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou, me ajudou bastante mesmo, no quesito da dúvida e lógica!
Agradecido, tenha um bom dia :)